# How to get the regular expression to return all capture groups?

Tags: python, regex

So I have a string `RAM 1000/2000/3000/4000` and I want to extract `RAM 1000`, `2000`, `3000` and `4000` from it using regular expressions.

So far I've `(RAM 1000)(?:(?:\/)(\w+)){1,}`, but it returns only `RAM 1000` and `4000`. How do I get it to return all the desired matches in Python?

Comment: Why not just use `str.split('/')`?

Answer (score 0):

While it does seem like `str.split` would do the job here, if you want to use regular expressions then you probably want to use `re.findall`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "RAM 1000/2000/3000/4000"
>>> re.findall(r"(?:RAM )?[^/]+", s)
['RAM 1000', '2000', '3000', '4000']
```